# How to create a parameterized insert using select query that includes some dynamic values for postgresql?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg, parameterized-query

I am using the nodejs pg package.  I have created some simple parameterized queries using the following format:

```
var client = new Client({user: 'brianc', database: 'test'});
client.on('drain', client.end.bind(client)); //disconnect client when all queries are finished
client.connect();

var query = client.query({
  text: 'SELECT name FROM users WHERE email = $1',
  values: ['brianc@example.com']
}, function(err, result) {
  console.log(result.rows[0].name) // output: brianc
});
```

But now I have some more complex queries to write where I am creating a copy of a record with a new name and description like the following:

```
var sNewName = 'new name', sNewDescription = 'new description';

INSERT INTO testtable (
    name,
    description,
    col3name,
    col4name,
    col5name,
) (
  SELECT 
    sNewName,
    sNewDescription,
    col3name,
    col4name,
    col5name
  FROM testtable
  WHERE
      id = 24
) RETURNING *;
```

On the [pg wiki](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Parameterized-queries-and-Prepared-Statements) they say the following regarding Parameterized Queries:

A parameterized query allows you "pass arguments" to a query, providing a barrier to SQL injection attacks.

Parameters may not be DDL:

- select name from emp where emp_id=$1 – legal
- select $1 from emp where emp_id=$2 – illegal – column cannot be parameter
- select name from $1 where emp_id=$2 – illegal – table cannot be parameter
- select name from $1.emp where emp_id=$2 – illegal – schema cannot be parameter

How then, is it possible to do the above query for copying a record, as a parameterized query?

I am using postgresql 9.5.3 and pg 6.1.2.

Thank your for your time.

Comment: You write is as you did. The column names are in the query, they are not parameters. The `24`, sNewName etc can be parameters

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen thanks for the comment mate.  I will do a POC and see how it goes.  It just didn't make sense to me given the comment that column can't work, and those variables are were column names would go.

Comment: They are constants so they can be parameters. Only column names cannot be. So it will work fine.

Comment: Indeed it does.  I should have done the POC before posting the question.  Thanks for taking the time to comment.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen One question I do have, is say I am doing an INSERT ON CONFLICT, and for the ID parameter I have: (_source_ds.data.id == -101 ? 'DEFAULT' : _source_ds.data.id)... it puts a 'DEFAULT' as a string instead of a KEYWORD and then throws the error of using a string for a type of int... how do I get around this?